# Getting 'getLastRealOrderId' once order has been placed

Tags: orders, ce-1.9.0.0

Once an order is placed in my magento store I have a custom module so that i can save the order number into an external database table.

My custom module setup is:

**Custom/ExternalOms/config.xml**

So i hook into the `sales_order_place_after` event

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_ExternalOms>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Custom_ExternalOms>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custom_externaloms>
                <class>Custom_ExternalOms_ExternalOms</class>
            </custom_externaloms>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <custom_externaloms>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Custom_ExternalOms_Model_ExternalOms</class>
                        <method>exportToOMS</method>
                    </custom_externaloms>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
       </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Custom/ExternalOms/Model/ExternalOms.php**

and run my function:

```
class Custom_ExternalOms_Model_ExternalOms extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function exportToOMS()
    {
        $_order_number = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();

        // remaining code..
    }
}
```

The code runs once the order has been placed correctly but this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
```

Is coming up empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put $observer in your function as parameter and Do anything like  give below.

```
class Custom_ExternalOms_Model_ExternalOms extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function exportToOMS($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); // this is order
        $orderid = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->grtId(); // this is orderid
        $incrementId= $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();  
       // this is increment id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get id from session

```
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
```

you can simple get it with `observer`

```
<sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <custom_externaloms>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Custom_ExternalOms_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>exportToOMS</method>
                    </custom_externaloms>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
```

Custom/ExternalOms/Model/Observer.php

```
class Custom_ExternalOms_Model_Observer {
    public function exportToOMS($observer)
        {
                $event = $observer->getEvent(); 
                $order = $event->getOrder();
                $order_id=$order->getEntityId();
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

write the exportToOMS in the observer.php file instead of adding in the model file with following changes in the code

```
<sales_order_place_after>
    <observers>
        <custom_externaloms>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Custom_ExternalOms_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>exportToOMS</method>
        </custom_externaloms>
    </observers>
</sales_order_place_after>
```

create Observer.php at Custom\ExternalOms\Model with following code in it

```
<?php
class Custom_ExternalOms_Model_Observer
{
    public function exportToOMS($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order_inc_id = $order->getIncrementId();
    }
}
```